# How to print in ASCII binary fields

Tags: string, python-2.7

I am familiar with C++ and I try to start to work with python.

From a serial line I manage to receive a string of binary characters (not ASCII) with python, let's say the rx 'buffer'.
I have to split this string into different fields, the method I am using is:

```
stx = (rx[0]) 
ctl = (rx[1])
node = (rx[2])
cTime = (rx[3:6])
nTime = (rx[7:10])
etx = (rx[11])
```

(currently I have not find a way to define a structure as for C++).

Now my problem is to print these fields as ASCII typically using:

```
print "%d-%d-%d-%ld-%ld-%d" % (stx,ctl,node,cTime,nTime,etx)
```

The error message is:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

I have already tried to convert the fields in different formats, but nothing works.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to convert your variables to `numbers` by `float(stx)` (or `int`) but if you only want to print them just use `%s` instead of `%d` which expects the variable to be a double (meaning float).

For example:

```
rx = '1' * 12
stx = float(rx[0]) 
ctl = float(rx[1])
node = float(rx[2])
cTime = float(rx[3:6])
nTime = float(rx[7:10])
etx = float(rx[11])

print "%d-%d-%d-%ld-%ld-%d" % (stx,ctl,node,cTime,nTime,etx)
```

prints

```
1-1-1-111-111-1
```

or with strings you change the last line:

```
print "%s-%s-%s-%s-%s-%s" % (stx,ctl,node,cTime,nTime,etx)
```

---

In case you are dealing with raw binary data you might need the builtin [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module.

As far as I understand it (given you haven't posted an actual content and desired output I cannot verify it) you might want something like:

```
import struct
stx, ctl, node, cTime, nTime, etx = struct.unpack('fffddf', rx)
```

That would expect 3 floats, 2 doubles and then again 1 float. If you have integer or other datatypes you must edit the `fffddf` string. See the [format types of `struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Brrr awfull

I have finally found one way for such a simple function:

```
> print int(stx.encode('hex'),16),int(ctl.encode('hex'),16),
> int(node.encode('hex'), 16), int(cTime.encode('hex'), 16),
> int(nTime.encode('hex'), 16),  int(etx.encode('hex'), 16)
```

Not sure I will like python